# How to hide a page before my content script has completed its DOM changes?

Tags: css, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm using content scripts to basically go trough the document, pull out the data and then rebuild large chunks of the page with different layouts but the same information. So it's a "preffity" extension for a specific website that looks awful.

Thing is, chrome goes ahead and renders the page before the content script has finished the process so on some page loads you can see the original page flash for a few frames before being replaced with the nicer one.

Browsers don't start rendering right away. You rarely see a website without its CSS applied because "it didn't make it in time". Is there a way to make the render wait for the content script too? I don't need hundreds of milliseconds, just a few.

Comment: If you are using css and adding it via manifest, try adding this to the content script field: `"run_at": "document_start"`.

Comment: @BeardFist, CSS files added via the manifest are always loaded before the DOM and before the content scripts, regardless of the `run_at` setting.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't **post your manifest.json** (always include this), but the most likely cause is that your script is a victim of [the default random firing time of a content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#run_at).

Probably, all you need to do is set `run_at` to `document_end` in your manifest.

---

---

However, if you absolutely, positively don't won't anything showing until your changes are finished, you need to use a multi-step approach:

1. Create a CSS file for your extension and save it as `hide_at_start.css`:

   ```
   body {
       display:    none;
   }
   ```

   Note that in rare cases, you might need to use `display: none !important;`
2. Add `hide_at_start.css` to your manifest and set the manifest to `run_at` `document_start`:

   ```
   {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "content_scripts": [ {
           "js":               [ "YOUR_CONTENT_SCRIPT.js" ],
           "css":              [ "hide_at_start.css" ],
           "matches":          [ "http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*"
                               ],
           "run_at":           "document_start"
       } ],
       "description":  "Blanks a page until our content script is done",
       "name":         "Blank at Start",
       "version":      "1"
   }
   ```
3. In your content script, any code that manipulates elements on the page must wait for the DOM to be `interactive` and for that element to be in place.  So modify `YOUR_CONTENT_SCRIPT.js` like so:

   ```
   document.addEventListener ('DOMContentLoaded', onDOM_Ready, false);

   function onDOM_Ready () {
       contentScript_main ();

       //-- Make page visible again.
       document.body.style.setProperty ("display", "inherit", "important");
   }

   function contentScript_main () {
       // PUT YOUR CODE, THAT ALTERS PAGE ELEMENTS, HERE.
   }
   ```

   Also, if your targeted content is added after page load, via AJAX, the content script must use additional tactics (timers, event listeners, mutation observers, etc.) for those elements.
4. Finally, if your code requires rendered dimensions or positions of elements (unlikely), use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;`.

Comment: Thanks but no. The page will be blinking white when a user is navigating trough the different parts of the site. Normally the browser will keep displaying the current page while loading the next one, up to a point. There's some time limit or heuristic used to decide when the first render is done. I'm asking whether I can communicate to Chrome that the page is not ready for render yet. I assumed it had to be possible because if it's not, any extension making extensive changes to pages is gonna suck.

Comment: No. In practice just setting `document_end` is all you need, and no one but you will notice anything amiss. You can't hold off the render without stopping the page completely.  All you can do is modify the page as it comes in.